# Pushing new Collection item to a GridView in a different class

Tags: c#, winforms, design-patterns, .net-3.5

I have a `LogOperations` class, which is a singleton, and it contains a collection of my `Log` object and a few methods for adding new `Log`s to the collection. `Log` only has 3 properties; `Message`, `Exception`, and `Time`.

On the only form in my application, I get a reference to `LogOperations`. Then I use its `Collection<Log> logs` property to build a data table out of each entry and throw that into a `GridControl` (gdcErrorLogs).

```
        gdcErrorLog.DataSource = logOps.GetLogsAsDataTable(); //Popualtes dt with each Log in logs
```

I have a bunch of other classes that perform all sorts of functions for the form, and whenever these functions catch an error I write that error to my `LogOperations`'s collection.

How can I make my form's grid automatically update with this new entry each time a `Log` gets added? I'm thinking of adding a reference to the form in my `LogOperations` class, and then at the end of my Add functions I'd just re-set the form's grid to be this new DataTable?

```
public class AddNewLogEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public Log log { get; private set; } // Error on compile see below
    public AddNewLogEventArgs(Log newLog) // Error on compile see below
    {
        log = newLog;
    }
}

class LogOps
{
    public delegate void AddNewLogHandler(object sender, AddNewLogEventArgs e);
    public event AddNewLogHandler OnAddNewLog;

    private Collection<Log> _logs;
    private static LogOps _singleton;

    private LogOps() 
    {
        _logs = new Collection<Log>();
    }

    public static LogOps Instance
    {
        get 
        {
            if (_singleton == null)
                _singleton = new LogOps();
            return _singleton;
        }
    }

    public void AddLog(string text)
    {
        Log newLog = new Log(text);
        _singleton._logs.Add(newLog);
        OnAddNewLog(new AddNewLogEventArgs(newLog), null);
    }

    public void AddLog(Log log)
    {
        Log newLog = log;
        _singleton._logs.Add(newLog);
        OnAddNewLog(new AddNewLogEventArgs(newLog), null);
    }

    public void AddLog(Exception ex)
    {
        Log newLog = new Log(ex.Message, ex.InnerException);
        _singleton._logs.Add(newLog);
        OnAddNewLog(new AddNewLogEventArgs(newLog), null);
    }

    public DataTable GetLogsAsDataTable()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Time");
        dt.Columns.Add("Error");
        dt.Columns.Add("Exception");

        int i = 0;
        foreach (Log log in _logs)
        {
            dt.Rows.Add();

            dt.Rows[i].SetField("Time", log.Time);
            dt.Rows[i].SetField("Error", log.Err);
            dt.Rows[i].SetField("Exception", log.Ex.Message);
            i++;
        }
        return dt;
    }
}
```

**Edit** Code sample was heavily modified since trying out King King's solution

The two flagged lines in the AddNewLogEventArgs give me these two errors:

- Error 1   Inconsistent accessibility: property type 'PrepareDeployment.Models.Log' is less accessible than property 'PrepareDeployment.Processes.AddNewLogEventArgs.log'
- Error 2 Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'PrepareDeployment.Models.Log' is less accessible than method 'PrepareDeployment.Processes.AddNewLogEventArgs.AddNewLogEventArgs(PrepareDeployment.Models.Log)'

Comment: What about the code of `GetLogsAsDataTable`?

Comment: I didn't think it was important, it's just a foreach that iterates over `Collection<Log> logs` and writes each property to a column in the data table.

Comment: but the `structure` of your `DataTable` is important. Does it have all the 3 columns `Exception, Message and Time`? and what's the type of `Exception` column? not sure if it's `System.Exception`.

Comment: Editted to include GetLogsAsDataTable. Still not really sure why it's important, the GridControl doesn't care what the table is. I just don't know how to "talk" to the GridControl from within `LogOperations`.

Comment: you have to declare the class `LogOps` as `public`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do something like this:

```
public delegate void AddNewLogEventHandler(object sender, AddNewLogEventArgs e);   
public event AddNewLogEventHandler AddNewLog;
public class AddNewLogEventArgs : EventArgs {
  public Log {get; private set;}
  public AddNewLogEventArgs(Log log){
    Log = log;
  }
}
protected virtual void OnAddNewLog(AddNewLogEventArgs e){
  AddNewLogEventHandler handler = AddNewLog;
  if(handler != null) handler(this, e);
}
public void AddLog(Exception ex) {
   Log newLog = new Log(ex.Message, ex.InnerException);
   singleton._logs.Add(newLog);       
   OnAddNewLog(new AddNewLogEventArgs(newLog));
}
public void AddLog(string text) {
   Log newLog = new Log(text);
   singleton._logs.Add(newLog);
   OnAddNewLog(new AddNewLogEventArgs(newLog));
}
```

In your main form (with your grid), you can do something like this:

```
LogOperations.Instance.AddNewLog += (s,e) => {
   var dt = (DataTable) gdcErrorLog.DataSource;
   dt.Rows.Add(e.Log.Time, e.Log.Err, e.Log.Ex.Message);
};
```

**NOTE**: You should remove the `private frmMain frm;` in your old class.

Comment: The issue is that I'm not sure how to properly pass a reference of the form to this `LogOperations` class... So I wouldn't be able to incorporate your last two lines, there.

Am I best off just making a method to set the instance if it's null? That seems poor.

Comment: @sab669 see my update, your `LogOperations` is implemented as a singleton, so you **must not** define any field to hold any outside instance

Comment: thanks, I tried implementing it but I was getting a few errors with your exact sample. I made some slight tweaks and now I'm getting two errors. I editted my post to my whole code sample. Could you take a look please? Thanks.

Comment: @sab669 I also left a comment under your question that your `LogOps` should be declared as `public`.